# Redelivery delay settings doesn't work on ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I've been trying to configure a jms endpoint (activemq 5.7) in my camel context (camel 2.8) so it should use redelivery of messages on rollback. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as I've expected: it returns back a message to a queue, but a consumer takes the message in despite of specified delay parameters immediately after that.

My configuration is the following:

```
...
<bean id="jmstx" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent"> 
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsTxConfig" /> 
</bean> 

<bean id="jmsTxConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration"> 
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsXaPoolConnectionFactory"/> 
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="osgiPlatformTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="transacted" value="false"/>
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_NONE"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${jms.concurrentConsumers}" />
</bean> 

<bean id="jmsXaPoolConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.XaPooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="${jms.maxConnections}" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsXaConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="osgiJtaTransactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsXaConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${jms.broker.url}"/>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
            <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="-1"/>
            <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="2000" />
            <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="5000" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

A small sample that demonstrates how I'm using the endpoint:

```
    <route id="main-route">
        <from uri="jmstx:queue:my-queue" />
        <to uri="direct:subroute" />
        ...
        <!-- some logic -->
    </route>

    <route id="subroute">
        <from uri="direct:subroute" />
        <transacted ref="PROPAGATION_MANDATORY"/>
        ...
        <!-- Rollback on some condition -->
        <rollback/>
        ...
    </route>
```

Does anyone knows why it happens?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I encountered same problem.
After hacking the ActiveMQ source code, and adding some logging information, I found some evidences and googled the solution.

Just like the answer said:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/266172
After setting cacheLevel to CACHE_CONSUMER on the activemq component, solved the problem.

ex:

```
<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration"> 
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsPooledConnectionFactory" />
  <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/> 
  <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
  <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER"/>
  <property name="acknowledgementModeName" value="SESSION_TRANSACTED"/>
</bean>
```